# Python - String of Digits to Integer using Recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

Say I have a string = '123' but I want to convert it into 123 without using the int() function. How would I go upon doing this using recursion?
The idea I have so far is to put the string into an array as such ['1','2','3'] and then convert them based on ASCII representations.

> for i in string:
>
> > myArr.append (ord(i) - ord('0'))

So now I'd have a list looking like [1,2,3]. What should I do next to recursively get 123?
I have an idea of using the place values and add them together (ie. 100 + 20 + 3 = 123), but I don't know how to do this. Any ideas would be helpful !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is an academic exercise, because it's a rather contrived thing to ask. Here's how, assuming that `s` represents an integer number greater than or equal to zero:

```
def strToInt(s, acc):
    if not s:
        return acc
    return strToInt(s[1:], 10 * acc + ord(s[0]) - 48)
```

Or even shorter:

```
def strToInt(s, acc):
    return strToInt(s[1:], 10 * acc + ord(s[0]) - 48) if s else acc
```

The trick is to accumulate the result of the conversion in an extra parameter, this has the nice side effect of yielding a tail-recursive solution (not that it matters much in Python, but still…). Also notice how we use `ord()` to get the numeric value of a character representing a digit, and by simply subtracting `48` we get to the actual digit's value. Test it, it works as expected:

```
strToInt('123', 0) # the accumulator always starts in zero
=> 123
```

Comment: An exercise given to me to practice recursion! I thought this was a ridiculous exercise when I can just use int() but I guess it's good practice to really understand recursion

Comment: The ridiculous part is not that you can use `int`, but that it can be solved with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

This wouldn't be recursive (I don't think you understand what that means), but:

```
for char in string:
    array.append(ord(char) - ord('0'))

array.reverse()

num = 0
for index, val in enumerate(array):
        num += val * (10 ** index)
```

EDIT: Ah, I see this is for an exercise. Yeah, it's a ridiculous problem to solve via recursion, but one of the other answers does it.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
def strToInt(s):
  if s:
    return (ord(s[-1]) - ord('0')) + 10 * strToInt(s[:-1])
  else:
    return 0
```

Comment: Recursive call should be `strToInt`

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is the famous C method atoi().
Python had a similar method, [also called atoi()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.atoi), but it was deprecated, with the instruction to use int().

Therefore, despite your comment, I would recommend using int(). Python documentation encourages you to use it, so do so without fear.

[int() documentation for Python 2.7](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#int)

[int() documentation for Python 3.3](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#int)